# How to print multiple lines of text with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I wanted to print multiple lines of text in Python without typing `print('')` for every line, is there a way to do that?

I'm using this for ASCII art in Python 3.5.1.

Comment: Yes there is and it is called a `for` loop...

Comment: This can be solved with a simple Google search. `"\n"` can be used for a new line character, or if you are printing the same thing multiple times then a for loop should be used.

Comment: You should have included how you are printing multiple lines *with* a print for every line.  The proper answer depends on where you are starting from.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can use *triple* quotes (single ' or double "):

```
a = """
text
text
text
"""

print(a)
```

Comment: this also works with f strings and raised errors

Comment: This can be paired with `textwrap.dedent(a)` to remove the indentation. Or even better - use print's argument `sep=os.linesep` as in Quba's answer.

Answer (score 48):

As far as I know, there are three different ways.

Use `os.linesep` in your print:

```
print(f"first line{os.linesep}Second line")
```

Use `sep=os.linesep` in print:

```
print("first line", "second line", sep=os.linesep)
```

Use triple quotes and a multiline string:

```
print("""
Line1
Line2
""")
```

Comment: This (especially the first two methods) is very useful for packages so that indentation does not get messed up.

Answer (score 15):

I wanted to answer to the following question which is a little bit different than this:

*[Best way to print messages on multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55167499/best-way-to-print-messages-on-multiple-line)*

He wanted to show lines from repeated characters too. He wanted this output:

```
----------------------------------------
# Operator Micro-benchmarks
# Run_mode: short
# Num_repeats: 5
# Num_runs: 1000

----------------------------------------
```

You can create those lines inside f-strings with a multiplication, like this:

```
run_mode, num_repeats, num_runs = 'short', 5, 1000

s = f"""
{'-'*40}
# Operator Micro-benchmarks
# Run_mode: {run_mode}
# Num_repeats: {num_repeats}
# Num_runs: {num_runs}

{'-'*40}
"""

print(s)
```

Comment: Any idea how to put an end to the back of these? I would like to do sometimes like this 

`while True:
   time.sleep(1)
   direction = ["left", "right", "up", "down"]
   x = random.choice(direction)
   print(x, end="\r")
`
thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The triple quotes answer is great for ASCII art, but for those wondering - what if my multiple lines are a tuple, list, or other iterable that returns strings (perhaps a list comprehension?), then how about:

```
print("\n".join(<*iterable*>))
```

For example:

```
print("\n".join(["{}={}".format(k, v) for k, v in os.environ.items() if 'PATH' in k]))
```

Comment: This might require adding a call to str() on the elements of the iterable, since `print` would normally do that, but `join` doesn't.

`print("\n".join([str(x) for x in iterable])`

Answer (score 0):

I realize it is an old thread, but my comment might help someone, so here it is:
for ASCII art you do not want escape char be and tried resolved, so putting "r" before the tripple quotes tells python it is a "raw" format multi-line comment, like:
print(r""" your art here """)