# How to start a new line in a print statement

Tags: python

I am trying to build an electronic mothers day card for my mom and am trying to make a message that i am going to display on the screen. However when I use a variable to store it as a string, I am not able to get it like this:

Dear mom, (new line)
....

Instead the words in the second line don't seem to be included in the quotations (they are not green in my editor like the rest). Here is my code:

```
card = "Dear mom,
        Happy mothers day!"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use more google

Comment: \n link break...

Comment: Just buy a card!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print multiple lines of text with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980251/how-to-print-multiple-lines-of-text-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

\r

card = "Dear mom, \r Happy mothers day!"

Answer (score 1):

```
card = 'Dear mom,\nHappy mothers day!'

card
```

output will be

```
'Dear mom,\n Happy mothers day!'

print(card)
```

output will be

```
Dear mom,
Happy mothers day!
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use triple quotes:

```
card = """Dear Mom,
Happy Mother's Day!"""
```

See python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)