# Reading matrix from a text file and storing it in an array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, text-files, binary-data

## Defintion

I have the following matrix stored in a text file:

```
 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
```

I want to read this matrix from the text tile and store it in a 2D array using python 2.7.

## Code I attempted

The code I attempted is as follows:

```
f = open('Matrix.txt')
triplets=f.read().split()
for i in range(0,len(triplets)): triplets[i]=triplets[i].split(',')
A = np.array(triplets, dtype=np.uint8)

print(A)
```

## Problem

As it stands the code above is printing the matrix in a 1D manner. Is it possible to save the matrix in a 2D manner as defined in the matrix above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print multiple lines of text with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980251/how-to-print-multiple-lines-of-text-with-python)

Comment: Give us the code which has at least no syntax error. How are you splitting by `,` as I cannot see in the matrix example? Missing `:` in for loop and indentation. Possible solution: List of lists can be interpreted as a 2-D matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

```
A = np.loadtxt('filename.txt')

>>> A
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Alternatively, you could read it line by line similarly to what you were doing (but this isn't efficient):

```
A = []
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        A.append(list(map(int,line.split())))

>>> np.array(A)
array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: thank you so much man! From all the solutions online yours is by far the simplest :)