# Best way to print messages on multiple lines

Tags: python

I have the following code to print message on multiple lines, but the code looks ugly to me. I come from a C background and want to learn a Pythonic way to do that.

```
    print ('-'*40)
    print("# Operator Micro-benchmarks \n
          # Run_mode: {} \n
          # Num_repeats: {} \n
          # Num_runs: {}"
          .format(run_mode, num_repeats, num_runs))
    print ('-'*40)
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------------
# Operator Micro-benchmarks
# Run_mode: short
# Num_repeats: 5
# Num_runs: 1000

----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use triple quotes to have multiline strings

```
a="""
{}
# Operator Micro-benchmarks
# Run_mode : short
# Num_repeats : 5
# Num_runs : 1000

{}
""".format('-'*40, '-'*40)
print(a)
```

Comment: There is a better solution. Unfortunately this question has been closed before I finished my answer. But I posted that here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980251/how-to-print-multiple-lines-of-text-with-python