# printing to multiple lines at the same time python

Tags: python

I am making a text based game and I am trying to print this code one character at a time on each column.

'''###############

Let us begin...

###############'''

I can't figure out how to make it come out one column at a time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print multiple lines of text with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980251/how-to-print-multiple-lines-of-text-with-python)

Comment: One line at a time or one column at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I still felt like answering this despite the vagueness of your question. Maybe this is what you are looking for, this prints one column at a time (one character per row):

```
import subprocess
import platform
from time import sleep


def clear_screen():
    # thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23075152/2923937
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        subprocess.Popen("cls", shell=True).communicate()
    else:
        print("\033c", end="")


# obviously you can create a function to convert your string into this
# list rather than doing it manually like I did, but that is another question :p.
views = ['#\nh\n#', '##\nhe\n##', '###\nhel\n###', '####\nhell\n####', '#####\nhello\n#####']

for view in views:
    clear_screen()
    print(view)
    sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I had meant.

Comment: It was a gamble, glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already doing `print(c, end='')` for each character in you string, just add `flush=True` to the call to `print()`. The sleep call will introduce enough delay so that you can see the characters print one at a time:

```
>>> import time
>>> s = '''###############
... Let us begin...
... ###############'''
>>> for c in s:
...    print(c, end='', flush=True)
...    time.sleep(0.1)
```